# processing data before presentation

Tags: grafana

I have dataset (from JSON source) with cumulative values. It looks like this:
[image]
Could I extract from this dataset delta from last hour or last day (for example, count from 0 since last midnight?)
[image]

Comment: Yes.  This assumes the JSON source has an array of timestamped values.

Comment: Yes, source have timestamp. I updated question and add new screenshot. How to do this delta?

Comment: To perform an **Hourly Delta**, you would probably want to use whole number of hours, which means you must linearly interpolate the respective values to align on the whole number of hours.  That is, using actual data values you need to calculate interpolated values.  I am guessing at some point in time there will be a reset to 0, so you must account for that.

Comment: To perform a **Daily Delta** may be trickier.  Usually JSON timestamps are in UTC, and you would want the day to coincide with a local time zone.  If that local time zone has DST, then you have to account for a "day" having 23 or 25 hours.  And like an hourly delta, it would require using actual recorded values to calculate interpolated values that coincide on midnight local time.

Comment: Ok, but how to implement it? I guess it is possible to do it at SQL query, but we talk about JSON data source - I don't know where I must preprocessing this data. I search for the best option in "Transform" properties but I can't find type of transformation for this task. Where in grafana I must preprocessing it before presentation?

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about falls squarely in the realm of **process data** as it usually comes from control systems aka process controls systems.  There may be **DCS** (Distributed Control Systems) or **SCADA** out in the field that act as a focal point on receiving data.  And there may be a process historian or time-series database for accessing that data, if not on an enterprise level at least not within the process controls network.

Much of the engineering associated with **process data** has been established for many, many decades.  For my examples, I did not want to write too many custom classes so I will use some everyday .NET objects.  However, I am adhering to 2 such well-regarded principles about **process data**:

1. All times will be in UTC.  Usually one does not show the UtcTime until the very last moment when displaying to a local user.
2. **Process Data** acknowledges the **Quality** of a value.  While there can be dozens of bad states associated with such Quality, I will use a simple binary approach of good or bad.  Since I use `double`, a value is good as long as it is not `double.NaN`.

That said, I assume you have a class that looks similar to:

```
public class JsonDto
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Time { get; set; }
    public double value { get; set; }
}
```

Granted your class name may be different, but the main thing is this class holds an individual instance of **process data**.  When you read a JSON file, it will produce a `List<jsonDto>` instance.

You will need lots of methods to transform the data to something a wee bit more useable in order to get to where the rubber finally meets the road: producing hourly differences.  But that requires producing hourly values because there is no guarantee that your recorded values occur exactly on each hour.

### ProcessData Class - lots of methods

```
public static class ProcessData
{
    public enum CalculationTimeBasis { Auto = 0, EarliestTime, MostRecentTime, MidpointTime }

    public static Dictionary<string, SortedList<DateTime, double>> GetTagTimedValuesMap(IEnumerable<JsonDto> jsonDto)
    {
        var map = new Dictionary<string, SortedList<DateTime, double>>();

        var tagnames = jsonDto.Select(x => x.Id).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x);
        foreach (var tagname in tagnames)
        {
            map.Add(tagname, new SortedList<DateTime, double>());
        }

        var orderedValues = jsonDto.OrderBy(x => x.Id).ThenBy(x => x.Time.ToUtcTime());
        foreach (var item in orderedValues)
        {
            map[item.Id].Add(item.Time.ToUtcTime(), item.value);
        }

        return map;
    }

    public static DateTimeKind UnspecifiedDefaultsTo { get; set; } = DateTimeKind.Utc;

    public static DateTime ToUtcTime(this DateTime value)
    {
        // Unlike ToUniversalTime(), this method assumes any Unspecified Kind may be Utc or Local.
        if (value.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified)
        {
            if (UnspecifiedDefaultsTo == DateTimeKind.Utc)
            {
                value = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            }
            else if (UnspecifiedDefaultsTo == DateTimeKind.Local)
            {
                value = DateTime.SpecifyKind(value, DateTimeKind.Local);
            }
        }
        return value.ToUniversalTime();
    }

    private static DateTime TruncateTime(this DateTime value, TimeSpan interval) => new DateTime(TruncateTicks(value.Ticks, interval.Ticks)).ToUtcTime();

    private static long TruncateTicks(long ticks, long interval) => (interval == 0) ? ticks : (ticks / interval) * interval;


    public static SortedList<DateTime, double> GetInterpolatedValues(SortedList<DateTime, double> recordedValues, TimeSpan interval)
    {
        if (interval <= TimeSpan.Zero)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException($"{nameof(interval)} TimeSpan must be greater than zero");
        }

        var interpolatedValues = new SortedList<DateTime, double>();

        var previous = recordedValues.First();
        var intervalTimestamp = previous.Key.TruncateTime(interval);

        foreach (var current in recordedValues)
        {
            if (current.Key == intervalTimestamp)
            {
                // It's easy when the current recorded value aligns perfectly on the desired interval.
                interpolatedValues.Add(current.Key, current.Value);
                intervalTimestamp += interval;
            }
            else if (current.Key > intervalTimestamp)
            {
                // We do not exactly align at the desired time, so we must interpolate
                // between the "last recorded data" BEFORE the desired time (i.e. previous)
                // and the "first recorded data" AFTER the desired time (i.e. current).
                var interpolatedValue = GetInterpolatedValue(intervalTimestamp, previous, current);
                interpolatedValues.Add(interpolatedValue.Key, interpolatedValue.Value);
                intervalTimestamp += interval;
            }

            previous = current;
        }

        return interpolatedValues;
    }

    private static KeyValuePair<DateTime, double> GetInterpolatedValue(DateTime interpolatedTime, KeyValuePair<DateTime, double> left, KeyValuePair<DateTime, double> right)
    {
        if (!double.IsNaN(left.Value) && !double.IsNaN(right.Value))
        {
            double totalDuration = (right.Key - left.Key).TotalSeconds;

            if (Math.Abs(totalDuration) > double.Epsilon)
            {
                double partialDuration = (interpolatedTime - left.Key).TotalSeconds;
                double factor = partialDuration / totalDuration;
                double calculation = left.Value + ((right.Value - left.Value) * factor);
                return new KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>(interpolatedTime, calculation);
            }
        }

        return new KeyValuePair<DateTime, double>(interpolatedTime, double.NaN);
    }

    public static SortedList<DateTime, double> GetDeltaValues(SortedList<DateTime, double> values, CalculationTimeBasis timeBasis = CalculationTimeBasis.Auto)
    {
        const CalculationTimeBasis autoDefaultsTo = CalculationTimeBasis.MostRecentTime;

        var deltas = new SortedList<DateTime, double>(capacity: values.Count);

        var previous = values.First();

        foreach (var current in values.Skip(1))
        {
            var time = GetTimeForBasis(timeBasis, previous.Key, current.Key, autoDefaultsTo);
            var diff = current.Value - previous.Value;
            deltas.Add(time, diff);
            previous = current; 
        }

        return deltas;
    }

    private static DateTime GetTimeForBasis(CalculationTimeBasis timeBasis, DateTime earliestTime, DateTime mostRecentTime, CalculationTimeBasis autoDefaultsTo)
    {
        if (timeBasis == CalculationTimeBasis.Auto)
        {
            // Different (future) methods calling this may require different interpretations of Auto.
            // Thus we leave it to the calling method to declare what Auto means to it.
            timeBasis = autoDefaultsTo;
        }
        switch (timeBasis)
        {
            case CalculationTimeBasis.EarliestTime:
                return earliestTime;
            case CalculationTimeBasis.MidpointTime:
                return new DateTime((earliestTime.Ticks + mostRecentTime.Ticks) / 2L).ToUtcTime();
            case CalculationTimeBasis.MostRecentTime:
                return mostRecentTime;
            case CalculationTimeBasis.Auto:
            default:
                return earliestTime;
        }
    }
}
```

### Usage Example

```
var inputValues = new List<JsonDto>();

// TODO: Magically populate inputValues

var tagDataMap = ProcessData.GetTagTimedValuesMap(inputValues);

foreach (var item in tagDataMap)
{
    // Following would generate hourly differences for the one Tag Id (item.Key)
    // by first generating hourly data, and then finding the delta of that.
    var hourlyValues = ProcessData.GetInterpolatedValues(item.Value, TimeSpan.FromHours(1));

    // Consider the difference between Hour(1) and Hour(2).
    // That is, 2 input values will create 1 output value.
    // Now you must decide which of the 2 input times you use for the 1 output time.
    // This is what I call the CalculationTimeBasis.

    // The time basis used will be Auto, which defaults to the most recent for this particular method, e.g. Hour(2)
    var deltaValues = ProcessData.GetDeltaValues(hourlyValues);

    // Same as above except we explicitly state we want the most recent time, e.g. also Hour(2)
    var deltaValues2 = ProcessData.GetDeltaValues(hourlyValues, ProcessData.CalculationTimeBasis.MostRecentTime);

    // Here the calculated differences are the same except the now
    // timestamp now reflects the earliest time, e.g. Hour(1)
    var deltaValues3 = ProcessData.GetDeltaValues(hourlyValues, ProcessData.CalculationTimeBasis.EarliestTime);
```

Comment: Thank You, it looks interesting!
In my case unfortunately I do not have impact to datasource. I just present data from JSON using Grafana. I think about it that I can do my own middle layer and receive JSON, calculate daily values then send it to Grafana. But I really need to simplify this and avoid middleware layer. Exist any way to do it only inside grafana, without modify my datasource?